# Representing geodesic compactifications of $S^1\times \Bbb R$ as analytic sections over base (analytic) foliations

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, gt.geometric-topology, differential-topology, fibre-bundles, foliations

Given a smooth nested set of "partial" foliations $\mathcal F_{\alpha}=\big\lbrace e^{\frac{\alpha}{\log x}}: \alpha \in (1/k,k), x\in(0,1),k\in [1,\infty) \big\rbrace$ of $X^2=(0,1)^2$ with $(X^2,g)$ and $g=\frac{dxdy}{xy}$ where $\mathcal F_{\alpha}$ preserves $g$ (in the sense that the infinitesimal flow tangent to the leaves preserves this metric) consider the sections $\sigma$, associated to each partial foliation, where $\pi: S^1 \times(0,1) \subset X^3 \longrightarrow \mathcal F_{\alpha} \subset(0,1)^2$ and $\sigma: F_{\alpha} \subset(0,1)^2 \longrightarrow S^1 \times(0,1) \subset X^3$ with $\pi(\sigma(x))=x$ $\forall x\in \mathcal F_{\alpha}\subset (0,1)^2$ and the $\mathcal F_{\alpha}$ lift to geodesics (meridians) on $S^1 \times (0,1)\subset X^3$. Note $\pi$ should be a $2:1$ covering map and $S^1 \times (0,1)$ should accumulate to $p=(0,1,1)$ and $q=(1,0,0)$. Perhaps a better phrasing is to say that the "accumulating cylinders" are geodesic compactifications of $S^1\times \Bbb R$, which we want to represent as sections of the base partial foliations $\mathcal F_{\alpha}.$ The collection $\bigcup_{k\in K}\mathcal F_k$ of partial foliations lifts to sections and those sections provide a foliation of $X^3-\lbrace l\rbrace$ where $l$ is a line connecting $p,q$. Here's a diagram of the situation with a generic section on the right and a generic base on the left (maybe $k=2$ for example - larger $k$ yields larger enclosed volume of the corresponding section):

[image]

> $\mathcal F_{\alpha}$ are real analytic objects. Can the sections $\sigma$ be made real analytic as well?

Comment: I don't understand the notation. The way it is written, I believe that $\mathcal F_\alpha=(0,1)$, but I guess something else is meant.

Comment: @SebastianGoette $\mathcal F_{\alpha}$ is the analytic foliation given locally by the functions $\varphi_{\alpha}(x)=e^{\frac{\alpha}{\log x}}$ where $\alpha$ indexes the leaves. Particularly, I take *pairs* of leaves, $\alpha=k$ and $\alpha=1/k$ and consider all leaves enclosed between these 2 leaves. That is what I call a "partial foliation" because it does not actually foliate the entire manifold $X^2=(0,1)^2$ but 
 it foliates a connected almost convex region, $R$, of $X^2$. Each $k\in(1,\infty)$ generates a diameter on $R$. As $k \to \infty$ one recovers a bonafide foliation of $X^2$

Comment: @SebastianGoette Then I associate an abstract section to each $R$. The sections live in $X^3$. The topology of these sections is prescribed to be a geodesic compactification of $S^1 \times \Bbb R$. So I want the projection map (a covering map) to send the meridian geodesics on the geodesic compactification of $S^1\times \Bbb R$ down to the leaves of $\mathcal F_{\alpha}$

Comment: @SebastianGoette and I'd like to understand how to prove that these sections can be made to be real analytic. so the mapping $\sigma$ should preserve analyticity. I believe describing a harmonic mapping between $R$ (say for example $k=2$) and the geodesic compactification of $S^1\times \Bbb R$ could be useful (essentially thinking of $R$ as a rubber sheet and stretching it around the the geodesic compactification of $S^1 \times \Bbb R$ s.t. the leaves of $F_{\alpha}$ precisely get stretched onto the meridian geodesics on the geodesic compactification of $S^1 \times \Bbb R$.

Comment: Thanks for the explanations. But my question was a bit simpler: you mean $\mathcal F_\alpha$ to be the graph of $x\mapsto e^{\frac\alpha{\log x}}$, don't you? Also, is "$\mathcal F_a$ preserves the foliation" equivalent to saying that it is a Riemannian foliation?

Comment: @SebastianGoette Yes, I mean $\mathcal F_{\alpha}$ to be the graph of $x \mapsto e^{\frac{\alpha}{\log x}}$. And yes, "$\mathcal F_{\alpha}$ preserves the foliation" is equivalent to saying that it is a (semi)-Riemannian foliation. $g$ describes Minkowski (1+1) space. Although, I will accept an answer that works with a Riemannian metric as well as the process of building the sections will be essentially identical in both the semi-Riemannian and Riemannian cases

Comment: @SebastianGoette Is the question clear now? Please see linked question